# How do I make camera follow an object while jumping only vertical on platforms?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am creating flash android game with as3. I already made object jumping on platforms, but I am facing problems with following object vertically. Any help or suggestion how to improve code are more than welcome!

The object instance name is `hero` and all platforms are made as one movie clip whose instance name is `level`

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

var Key:KeyObject = new KeyObject(stage);
var dy:Number=10;
var gravity:Number=1;    
var canjump:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onenter);

function onenter(e:Event) :void {

    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
    hero.x-=30;
    hero.y-=10;
    }

    if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
    hero.x+=30;
    hero.y-=20;
    }


    dy+=gravity;

    if (! level.hitTestPoint(hero.x,hero.y,true)) {   //if the hero not hitting the platform
        hero.y+=dy;
    }
    if (dy>10) {   //controls gravity
        dy=10;
    }
    for (var i:int = 0; i<10; i++) {
        if (level.hitTestPoint (hero.x,hero.y,true)) {   
            hero.y--;
            dy=0;
            canjump=false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure whether it would work on android but on my code for some other platformer, I used the script

```
this.y=-hero.y+(stage.stageWidth/2);
```

this follows the character as he ascends, in the swf file at least; hope it helps!

Comment: Well it works partly. Now my object is flying to the top till it stops in half way and camera is following it. But the thing is I guess something wrong in my code, because now platforms are not working and my object is flying.. Any suggestions on that?

Thanks by the way for your previous help!